# AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values but cells contain date time

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I encounter the following error when using Pandas. I looked for other solutions on StackOverflow but they didn't solve my error.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv_content_below.csv")
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].dt.tz_convert(timezone_for_plot)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5137, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 187, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py", line 480, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

DataFrame:

```
>>> df["timestamp"]
0       2021-09-01 04:59:46+00:00
1       2021-09-01 04:59:46+00:00
2       2021-09-01 04:59:37+00:00
3       2021-09-01 04:59:37+00:00
4       2021-09-01 04:59:24+00:00
                  ...            
1418    2021-09-01 04:56:50-04:00
1419    2021-09-01 04:56:25-04:00
1420    2021-09-01 04:56:24-04:00
1421    2021-09-01 04:56:14-04:00
1422    2021-09-01 04:56:14-04:00
Name: timestamp, Length: 1423, dtype: object
```

Data type:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> assert all([type(x) is datetime for x in df["timestamp"]])
True
```

DataFrame stored as CSV can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pems8yRocGPfnvubW5ghPL59xeX5oMDN/view?usp=sharing). Here's a sample for future reference:

```
,timestamp
0,2021-09-01 04:59:46+00:00
1,2021-09-01 04:59:46+00:00
2,2021-09-01 04:59:37+00:00
3,2021-09-01 04:59:37+00:00
4,2021-09-01 04:59:24+00:00
5,2021-09-01 04:59:24+00:00
6,2021-09-01 04:59:14+00:00
7,2021-09-01 04:59:14+00:00
8,2021-09-01 04:59:03+00:00
9,2021-09-01 04:59:03+00:00
...
```

Comment: Your format string is incorrect for the content you've shared. `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f'` will fix the issue of it not converting to datetime64

Comment: Thank you, and sorry. I have fixed both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `utc=True` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv_content_below.csv")
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], utc=True)
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].dt.tz_convert(timezone_for_plot)
```